# How to transfer the data of a variable from one Activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, android-handler

I want to transfer the value of one `EditText` or say the value of a variable from an `Activity` to another `Activity`.

I am i supposed to do the following using a `Handler` or What?

If using `Handler` then How am i supposed to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is using the intent extras.

To send a data, use something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Edit Text data", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then retrieve it as

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("Edit Text data");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences to store the data in the former activity, and then later retrieve it in the child activity.

Using Shared Prefences, you can store the value of editText like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Elena");
 editor.putInt("idName", 12);
 editor.commit();
```

Now, in the other activity, you can retrieve it as

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
  int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
}
```

Check this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riyMQiHY3V4) out. Or you can also check this [tutorial](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2015/02/android-shared-preferences-example-and-tutorial.html#.WH4xP_l97IU) out.

Comment: Is there a simple way. Can we do it using instance or handler?? And if i don't want to make a as a derived activity.

Answer (score 0):

In first activity you should put extra argument to intent like this:

```
EditText editText;
edittextIntent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class); 
intent.putExtra("arg",editText.getText()); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in second activity you retrive argument like this:

```
String passedArg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("arg");
```

Answer (score 0):

if use a `Handler` i think only required simple validate with `hasExtra()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
String value = editText.getText().toString().trim();
intent.putExtra("data", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("value")) {
   String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
   Log.d("MI_VALUE", value);
 }
```